# C# ListView: ListViewItem offset possible?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, listviewitem, offset

I was wondering... I have a WinForms System.Windows.Forms.ListView with a bunch of ListViewItems that I'm drawing using the View.List style. Each ListViewItem has a "SmallIcon" that I fetch from the ListView's SmallImageList.

My problem is that the icons are showing too close to the border on the left. I've tried to change the bounds and the ListViewItem's Position property to no avail.

Is there anyway to have some kind of offset to ListViewItems?

Comment: any chance to show a screeshot? Jing is your friend: www.jingproject.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Win32 listview control doesn't have any setting to increase the space between the icon and the label (in any view, not just List). Setting `ListViewItem.Position` does nothing when the `ListView` is in `List` view.

A low-tech solution would be to simply prefix every ListViewItem's `Text` value with a single space. Slightly ugly, but oh so easy to do.

If you really want to have pixel level control, you will have to owner draw it. As always, if you are doing anything with a .NET ListView, [ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ObjectListView.aspx) makes owner drawing your items trivial.

Comment: I know I took a long time to accept this as the answer, but I finally ended up going your "prefix every ListViewItem's Text value with a single space" solution. It works but slightly ugly as you said.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned already, prefixing the text of all your items with a space is a super simple way to add padding.  This has a pretty significant drawback, however.  Once you do this, you lose the ability to find items in the ListView by simply starting to type their name while the ListView has focus.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding white space to the left of your small images.

If you're using 16x16 images change to 24x16 for example by adding 8 white (or ListView Background color) pixels to the left.

Comment: simpel but effective! Good answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are in ListView View LargeIcons then you can postion the text using item.position

Answer (score 0):

A screenshot would be nice for an example to see exactly what you're after.

Funny thing... the Windows Explorer uses the ListView to display files and folders. i usually run my view in Report or Detail mode. i just switched it to List view mode and see the exact problem that you're describing! Yikes. Might be a bug with the Win32 object and that particular view type!

A quick workaround might be to use a Report style for the ListView with a single column or perhaps implement something yourself. The FlowLayoutPanel in .Net would work very nicely as a starting point for a custom list view.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the [`View.List`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.view.aspx) style, I suspect you'll either need to implement some custom drawing or consider padding your images. You could also look at overriding the ListView control and manipulating it's bounds by overriding [`SetBoundsCore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.setboundscore.aspx) or [`SetClientSizeCore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.setclientsizecore.aspx) (or similar).

However, if the [`ListView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx) were set-up for [`View.Details`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.view.aspx) view, this could be done using the [`ListViewItem.IndentCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.indentcount.aspx) property:

> The IndentCount property can be used
>   only when the View property of the
>   containing ListView is set to Details,
>   and the SmallImageList property of the
>   ListView is set. *Source:[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.indentcount.aspx)*

Comment: IndentCount works in multiples of the SmallImageList width. So setting IndentCount to 1, indents the text by 16 pixels (if the SmallImageList is 16x16). I think that is more than @Superoli needs :)

Answer (score 0):

If you set the StateImageList property you can add a space of 16 px before the icons. I think you can adjust this additional space by loading an image with matching width as first entry into the StateImageList. But I have not tested this.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284116/why-is-this-gap-showing-up-in-my-listview)  discusses the opposite problem.